# Update dev dependencies using Poetry >1.20

Tags: python-poetry

In my `pyproject.toml` I have some dev dependencies configured as follows:

```
[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
mypy = "^0.971"
```

A simple `poetry show -l` shows that I indeed have `mypy` installed with version 0.971. Currently, the latest version available is v0.991.

What's the correct syntax to have all my dependencies - including dev dependencies - being updated.

`poetry update --with=dev` is not going to update `mypy` to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`poetry update` updates dependencies within the version range given in the `pyproject.toml`.

`^0.971` translates to `>=0.971,<0.972` (See: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements). This is why `poetry update` will not update `mypy` to `0.991`.

To get the latest version of a dependency you have to use `poetry add <dep>@latest`. In your case `poetry add -G dev mypy@latest`.

At the moment there is no Poetry command to bump all dependencies to its latest version outside of the given version ranges. But there is a feature request for it: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/461

Comment: I changed it to ``^0`` and now ``poetry update --with=dev`` is working properly :-)